# Custom Elements: Can both a class and its super run a connectedCallback?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I have a class called `QueryAddable`

```
class QueryAddable extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('QueryAddable');
  }
```

It has several classes that extend it, such as

```
class QueryGroup extends QueryAddable {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('QueryGroup');
  }
```

Optimally, if I put `<query-group>` on the page, I'd like to see `QueryAddable` and `QueryGroup` logged in the console. I suppose it's not happening because I only have `<query-group>` on the page and not `<query-addable>`.

I could very well put a method in `QueryAddable` called `onLoad` and call that in the `connectedCallback` of each extending class, but why should I have to do it in multiple places instead of one?

Is there any way to get both `connectedCallback` functions to run, or is it setup so that only one can run?

Comment: Just call `super.connectedCallback()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
class Parent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('PARENT COMPONENT');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    console.log('CHILD COMPONENT');
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-child', Child);
```

```html
<my-child></my-child>
```

Comment: Please do not call `connectedCallback` yourself especially not in the constructor. You may go against the rules of a Component Constructor: https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance

Comment: @Intervalia your link is about constructors. The only thing it says about `connectedCallback` is that most work should be deferred to `connectedCallback`, and that initializations done in `connectedCallback` should have a check to make sure they're only done once.

Comment: If you call `connectedCallback` from your constructor then the rules still apply. Which is why I *HIGHLY* recommend not calling `connectedCallback` yourself, especially not from a constructor. `connectedCallback` _should_ only be called by the browser when your component it added to a valid document.

Comment: @BennyHinrichs He is right about the constructor, I just gave you an example that you could call it almost everywhere, by the way is well known that the constructor is used for initializations and not for side affects like API calls and so on.I've removed the constructor example so it won't force people do side effects there.

Comment: @idmitrov I just checked the edits and see that you originally had the `connectedCallback` in the constructor, so I understand his comment now :) Thanks for your replies

Comment: Are there any pro/cons in passing data? ``super.connectedCallback('foo');``